# Hint shown for parameter of type long not correct

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer

The API explorer UI shows a hint (in parentheses) next to the text box for the parameter. If the parameter is of type long, the hint shown is `(String)`, which is incorrect. If the parameter is of type double, the hint shown is `(Number)`, which *is* correct.

Is this a bug in the API explorer or is there something I should do to fix the hint for long types?

Edit:

Just to clarify, this is observed with an API we have built with Google Endpoints.

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit: what API shows this? Specifically, is this a Google API or an Endpoints API?

It might also be relevant that, some frameworks cannot handle longs, meaning they relay them as strings. This might be what you are seeing.

Comment: Added further clarification to the original problem text above.

Comment: If you add the tag 'google-cloud-endpoints' to your question, it might get more attention from people familiar with that product specifically.